# Turn on Indicator LED if Moisture Sensor Value >= MaxDryness for longer than 20 min

Tags: sensors, led

Hi so I am making a self watering flower pot with a moisture sensor and a peristaltic pump, the code is as follows:

[image]

I want to add an indicator LED which turns on if the sensor value has been equal to or greater than MaxDryness for longer than twenty minutes.

How would I alter the code to do that?

Comment: why did you post a picture of the code? ... do you really think that someone will spend time typing it in so that it could be added to, and posted as an answer?

Comment: Ditch the `delay()` calls and learn the non-blocking coding style from the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example. It uses the `millis()` function, that returns the milliseconds since startup. You can use this as a clock to time the 20min. The coding style has been explained many times on the web.

Comment: @jyc43 please replace your source code picture with [a `code` block](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code), this will allow us to insert the lines of code you are looking for.

Comment: Please code the text as text

Answer (score 2):

Following is an example how it could be coded.

Remember that the soil is dry by setting `DrySoil = true`.

Register the time at which a dry period starts in DrySoilBegin.

Check at each 'dry' reading whether DrySoil was true for more than 20 minutes.

Set `DrySoil = false` at every 'not dry' reading.

The `ul` after the constant `1200000` makes it an unsigned long value. This because `millis()` returns a `unsigned long` result. I am not 100% sure this is necessary (maybe the compiler takes care of this automatically).

As I don't have a plant watering system I couldn't verify the proper working..

```
#define WATERPIN 10
#define READSOILPIN A0
#define LEDPIN 13

// higher number is more dry
#define MAXDRYNESS 700

#define WATERDELAY 10000
#define WATERPOSTDELAY 5000

bool DrySoil = false; // State of soil
unsigned long DrySoilBegin; // Time when DrySoil became true

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(READSOILPIN, INPUT);
  pinMode(WATERPIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LEDPIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  int SensorValue = analogRead(READSOILPIN); //take a sample
  Serial.print(SensorValue);
  Serial.print(" ־ ");

  if(SensorValue >= MAXDRYNESS) {
    // Soil is too dry
    // Check if soil was already in a dry state
    if(DrySoil){
      // If already in a dry state check the duration
      if((millis()-DrySoilBegin) > 1200000ul){
        // If duration is longer than 20 minutes switch LED on
        //   or keep LED switched on
        digitalWrite(LEDPIN, HIGH);
      }
    }
    else{
      // First 'dry' result after 'wet' result(s)
      DrySoil = true; // Set DrySoil in true state
      DrySoilBegin = millis(); // Set beginning of DrySoil period
    }
    // start watering for 10 seconds then
    //    wait for 5 seconds before monitoring again
    Serial.println("Soil dry start watering");
    digitalWrite(WATERPIN, HIGH);
    delay(WATERDELAY); // wait until WATERDELAY milliseconds have passed
    digitalWrite(WATERPIN, LOW);
    delay(WATERPOSTDELAY); // wait until WATERPOSTDELAY milliseconds have passed
  }
  else{
    // Soil is not too dry
    DrySoil = false; // Set or keep DrySoil in state false
    digitalWrite(LEDPIN, LOW); // Switch LED off, or keep it switched off
    delay(50); // Wait 50 ms before next sampling
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. You should move your first `else` down so that it matches `if(DrySoil)`. 2. You should replace `while((millis()-TimerStart)<...` by `delay()`. Using `millis()` in this _blocking_ fashion has zero advantage over `delay()` and it makes the code harder to read.

Comment: 1. Thank you, you are right. Have edited accordingly. 2. My guess was, this left more internal processes running. But I understand this is not true. Also corrected accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little example how to do it. Adapt this way(if you want) by yourself.

```
// GLOBAL VARIABLES
unsigned long lowSensorTick = 0;
bool dry = false;

void loop()
{
    if (analogRead(/* PIN */) > /* THRESHOLD VALUE */)
    {
        // DRY
        if (dry == false)
        {
            lowSensorTick = millis();
            dry = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (millis() - lowSensorTick > 720000) // 720000ms = 12min * 60000ms (1s = 1000ms) 
            {
                digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH); // LED GOES HIGH/ON
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // WET
        dry = false;
        digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW); // LED GOES LOW/OFF
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that zero is a perfectly valid timestamp. You should use a separate boolean variable, like in PimV's answer, rather having `lowSensorTick` perform double duty of storing the timestamp and a "timestamp valid" state.

Comment: Why? millis() will never return zero as value. I use this way in my projects and it works without any problem.

Comment: `millis()` returns zero at the beginning of the program run, and then once again every 49.7 days.

Comment: At the begining you have pinMode function. Zero stays for 1/1000s. For overflow that's another problem.

Comment: 1. `pinMode()` executes in way less than a millisecond. 2. `lowSensorTick = 0` is a kludge to shoehorn a valid/invalid status info into a variable that is meant to hold something else, and this can make the program misbehave, albeit very rarely. Other than laziness, there is no reason to not use a separate Boolean. If you want to take the (very tiny) risk on you own programs, that's OK. But when answering questions, you should avoid teaching bad practices, especially considering that there is already a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: @EdgarBonet fixed.